# Prefilled slider value, jumps always back to default state of prefilled api data

Tags: reactjs, input, slider, state, use-effect

Hello i have a prefilled slider which is for rating, i prefill it with data from the API and if a user slides i like to update the API Database. Everything works fine except the slider always jumps back to the prefilled value by useEffect. How can i change the state so that the value from the user takes precedence over the prefilled value ?

This is my code:

```
const [ user ] = useContext(Context);
const location = useLocation();
const { pathname } = location;
const splitLocation = pathname.split("/");
const movieId = splitLocation[2];

const [ MovieResults, setMovieResults ] = useState([]);
const [ value, setValue ] = useState(5);

useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true; 
    
    fetch(`${API_URL}account/xxxxxxxx/rated/movies?api_key=${API_KEY}&session_id=${user.sessionId}&sort_by=created_at.desc`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => isMounted ? setMovieResults(data.results) : null)
        .then(isMounted ? MovieResults.forEach((arrayItem) => { 
            if(arrayItem.id.toString() === movieId.toString()) {
               setValue(arrayItem.rating);  
            }
        }) : null)
       

    return () => { isMounted = false };
},[user.sessionId, MovieResults, movieId]);

const changeSlider = (e) => {
    // This value should override the default value from the api 
    setValue(e.currentTarget.value);
};

return (
    <div>
        <input 
            type="range" 
            min="1" 
            max="10" 
            className="rate-slider"
            value={value} 
            onChange={e => changeSlider(e)}
        />
        {value}

        <p>
            <button className="rate-button" onClick={() => callback(value)}>Rate</button>
        </p>
    </div>
)
```

Thanks help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it. I needed to give one of the two setValue precedence over the other based on the condition that the user slided the slider. Up to now i didnt know useRef, with this hook i could manage it. Here is the code:

```
  const [ user ] = useContext(Context);
const location = useLocation();
const { pathname } = location;
const splitLocation = pathname.split("/");
const movieId = splitLocation[2];

const [ MovieResults, setMovieResults ] = useState([]);
const [ value, setValue ] = useState(5);
const ref = useRef(0);

useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true; 
    
    fetch(`${API_URL}account/jensgeffken/rated/movies?api_key=${API_KEY}&session_id=${user.sessionId}&sort_by=created_at.desc`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => isMounted ? setMovieResults(data.results) : null)
        .then(isMounted ? MovieResults.forEach((arrayItem) => { 
            if(arrayItem.id.toString() === movieId.toString()) {
                
                    //console.log(ref.current)
               if(ref.current === 0) {
                    setValue(arrayItem.rating);
               }  
            }
        }) : null)
       

    return () => { isMounted = false };
},[user.sessionId, MovieResults, movieId]);

const handleSlide = (e) => {
    ref.current = e.currentTarget.value
    setValue(ref.current);
}


return (
    <div>
        <input 
            type="range" 
            min="1" 
            max="10" 
            className="rate-slider"
            value={value} 
            onChange={e => handleSlide(e)}
        />
        {value}

        <p>
            <button className="rate-button" onClick={() => callback(value)}>Rate</button>
        </p>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your general approach, this seems to work fine for me:

```js
const fetch = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => 
  resolve({json: () => ({rating: 4})})
, 1000));

const App = () => {
  const [sliderVal, setSliderVal] = React.useState(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("foo")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setLoading(false);
        setSliderVal(data.rating);
      });
  }, []);
  
  const handleSliderChange = evt => {
    setSliderVal(evt.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>    
      {loading 
        ? <p>loading...</p>
        : <div>
            <input
              type="range" 
              min="1" 
              max="10" 
              value={sliderVal}
              onChange={handleSliderChange}
            />
            {sliderVal}
          </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for anwsering appreciate but what does the timeout should do ? I finally managed to solve it with the usage of ref (useRef()).

Comment: Glad you worked it out! I'm mocking `fetch` to return fake data so the code is runnable and reproducible without an external dependency.